# How to define and use the date format "1 Jan 2012 7.03am"

Tags: datetime

How can I define and use the date format "1 Jan 2012 7.03am"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here, in the hope that other people might find this information useful. The answer is to use

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\settimeformat{ampmtime}
\newdateformat{mydate}{\THEDAY{ }\shortmonthname{ }\THEYEAR{ }\currenttime}
```

and then

```
\mydate\today
```

where you want to insert the date and time.

Comment: It would be better if you expanded the answer to cover also other date formats (for example in different languages).

Comment: Unfortunately a bug in `ampmtime` makes 12.22pm come up as "12.22 noon"!